# Capitalizing certain chars in a string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm looking for a way to convert only upper case letters into lower case letters from a user inputted string. The problem is that my conditional is ignored, and every character is changed, not just the upper case ones. For the record I also tried converting the chars into ints using atoi but encountered the same issue as above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char letter[100];
    scanf("%s", letter);
    int i;
    for(i=0; letter[i]!='\0'; i++){
        if((letter[i]>='A')||(letter[i]<='Z')){
            letter[i]=letter[i]+32;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", letter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: || should be &&. Voting to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using library functions, like `islower()`, `isupper()`, `toupper()` and `tolower()` for this. In your case, you could do it like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(letter); i++)
{
    letter[i] = tolower(letter[i]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added the example to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `tolower()` function instead:

```
#include <ctype.h>
for(i = 0; i < strlen(letter); i++){
    letter[i] = tolower(letter[i]);
}
```

The `tolower()` function converts upper case letters into lower case letters. Note that to use it, you have to include `ctype.h`.

Otherwise, the problem with your code is that you use `||` instead of `&&`. You're testing if the letter is less than `'Z'` OR greater than `'A'`, which is always true. What you wanted to do is test if it's between `'Z'` and `'A'`, which means that you should test if it's less than `'Z'` AND greater than `'A'`.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is that you say

```
if((letter[i]>='A')||(letter[i]<='Z')){
    letter[i]=letter[i]+32;
}
```

instead of

```
if((letter[i]>='A')&&(letter[i]<='Z')){
    letter[i]=letter[i]+32;
}
```

Comment: That's an unwarranted assumption of the ASCII character set that's not supported by [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  It's non-portable.  Per **5.2.1 Character sets**, *only* the digits `'0'`-`'9'` are guaranteed to be represented sequentially.

Comment: It is true, though it seems like OP wanted to do it that way. :)

Comment: @AndrewHenle In practice, it's work on all platforms.

Comment: @Stargateur *In practice, it's work on all platforms.*  [Not true.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_mainframe).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can easily be solved with something like `_Static_assert('Z' - 'A' == 25, "Your computer either got some virus or EBCDIC. Get lost. Your problem not mine");`. To include such a line in your source code is perfectly fine practice.

Comment: @Lundin All to avoid a standard-compliant, *portable* call to `tolower()`?  Do you really set out to write *deliberately non-portable* code like that?!?!!?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Of course. By making my code non-portable to EBCDIC systems, I'm doing humanity a favour.

Comment: The portable version would be: `letter[i] = tolower(letter[i]);` **Note 1:** Don't need to test if it is uppercase since tolower doesn't change letters that aren't uppercase. **Note 2:** This will also convert other uppercase letters to lowercase, such as the German Ä (depending on locale).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck But in case you are using letters beyond the 127 bit ASCII, wouldn't you rather use `wchar_t`? In which case you would be using `towlower()` and not `tolower()`.

Comment: @Lundin 8 bit ascii (ISO8859-1 or CP1252) works for me. But you are right, the world has moved on to various representations of unicode.